# Where to store files for Azure function?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have files that I reference from inside by C# code such as:

```
public static string Canonical()
{
    return File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\myapp\\" + "CanonicalMessage.xml");
}
```

**How do I reference this file from within an Azure Function?**

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var data = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\\myapp\\" + "CanonicalMessage.xml");

    //etc
}
```

**Perhaps I can simply embed this resource in the project?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, put the file at the root of Azure Function project and set its property `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`. Use code below.

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var data = File.ReadAllText(context.FunctionAppDirectory+"/CanonicalMessage.xml");

    //etc
}
```

Check the [doc](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function) for more details.

If we need to add this file from anywhere locally, right click on Function project, `Edit <FunctionProjectName>.csproj`. Add Item below, relative or absolute path are both ok.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="c:\\myapp\\CanonicalMessage.xml">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: does it matter which project i put that file in as long as i set the property to `copy to output directory`  ??? can i put it in any project in any folder so long as it exists within the solution?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' We can put it anywhere we want, just make sure we copy it to function output directory when project built. See my update.