# Location for SSH private key and temporary SFTP download data in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, winscp, winscp-net

I am writing an Azure function that uses WinSCP library to download files using SFTP and upload the files on blob storage.  This library doesn't allow to get files as a `Stream`. Only option is to download them locally. My code also uses a private key file. So i have 2 questions.

1. `sessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPath = Path.GetFullPath("privateKey2.ppk");`
   is working locally. I have added this file in solution with option "copy to output" and it works. But will it work when Azure function is deployed?
   [image]
2. While getting the files I need to specify local path where the files will be downloaded.

   ```cs
   var transferResult = session.GetFiles(
       file.FullName, Path.GetTempPath() + @"SomeFolder\" + file.Name, false,
       transferOptions);
   ```

   The second parameter is the local path.

   What should I use in place of `Path.GetTempPath()`  that will work when Azure function is deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the private key, just deploy it along with your function project. You can simply add it to your VS project.

See also [Including a file when I publish my Azure function in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46537758/850848).

---

For the download: The latest version of WinSCP already supports streaming the files. Use the [`Session.GetFile` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfile).

To answer your question about the temporary location, see:

- [Azure Functions Temp storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46294790/850848).
- [Where to store files for Azure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53367132/850848)